# JerseyTest passes empty entity to jersey REST resource

Tags: java, junit, jersey, jetty, hibernate-validator

**The test:**

```
public class OrderResourceTest extends JerseyTest {
    @Override
    public Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        return new ResourceConfig(OrderResource.class);
    }
    @Test
    public void testCreate(){
        Order order = new Order(0, new Customer(0, "CompanyName", "Street", "123456", "City", "UK"), Arrays.asList(new OrderLine(0, "s345664lkdLDSDf", "Samsung Galaxy 4", 1)));
        Response output = target("/orders")
                .request()
                .post(Entity.entity(order, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        assertEquals("Should return status 201", 201, output.getStatus());
    }
}
```

JUnit runs the test with `org.glassfish.jersey.test.jetty.JettyTestContainerFactory$JettyTestContainer`, `Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final`

**JUnit output:**

```
INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > POST http://localhost:9998/orders
1 > Content-Type: application/json
{"customer":{"customerId":0},"orderId":0,"orderLines":[{}]}

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL []; NULL not allowed for column "COMPANY_NAME"; SQL statement

org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter log
INFO: 1 * Client response received on thread main
1 < 201
1 < Content-Type: application/json
1 < Location: http://localhost:8080/api/orders/0
1 < Server: Jetty(9.1.1.v20140108)
1 < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
{"customer":{"customerId":0},"orderId":0,"orderLines":[{}]}
```

**The OrderResource**

```
@Path("/orders")
public class OrderResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createOrder(Order order) {
        Order savedOrder = new OrderService().saveOrder(order); 
        return Response.status(Response.Status.CREATED)
                .entity(savedOrder)
                .header("Location",
                        "http://localhost:8080/api/orders/"
                                + String.valueOf(savedOrder.getOrderId()))
                .build();
    }
}
```

**Customer class with Hibernate validator annotations:**

```
public class Customer {
    private long customerId;
    @NotNull
    private String companyName;
    @NotNull
    private String street;
    @NotNull
    private String postalCode;
    @NotNull
    private String city;
    @NotNull
    private String country;

    public Customer(long customerId, String companyName, String street, String postalCode, String city, String country) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.street = street;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
    }

   // gettes, setters and empty constructor
}
```

Why the test passes/ posts empty object to `OrderResource`? How to configure Hibernate Validator so it would return appropriate error response (currently it passes wrong data to database, hence there is `DataIntegrityViolationException`)? How to make it all work?

The applications is pretty much like this:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/griz_jersey_intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html

**UPDATE**
It seems like marshaling or unmarshaling went quite wrong.

**Sending:**
[image]
**Receiving:**
[image]

Comment: Try adding `@Valid` next to the `Order` method parameter, and probably on the `Customer` field in the `Order` class. Also have a look at [the docs for bean validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html)

Comment: Now, after wrong data reaches database and thrown `DataIntegrityViolationException` then `org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBBeanValidator` throws `org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.BeanValidationException.constraintViolation`. Quite strange since it has to validate first and then decide to proceed with datanase query...

Comment: It should never even reach the dao if you did `createOrder(@Valid Order order)`. Jersey will validate before it goes into the method. At least it _should_